# Is Kerrigan Level achievement bugged?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

[image]

---

[image]

I believe this achievement is bugged. Is it normal? Shall I ticket Blizzard about this? Or is there something I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I played my HOTS through the first time, I didnt reach level 70 at first, and didnt get the achvement, obviously. Then I did it on Brutal, and didnt get 70 again. But when I started to do the missions seperatly (after Brutal and to get the missing achievements) I got the achivement, even from playing one of the first Char missions (where your not suposed to be level 70). 
It stacked my levels from the Brutal playtrough and then doing the seperate missions.
Why? I dont know!

But It would seem, judging from your screens, that you played some of the missions before, or have re-started the game once, just to start over on the campaign. So that the level achivement will stack up from the games you play.

My conclusion, based on my experience, is that the levels in the achivement stack up through seperate campaign plays.

EDIT: See the dates of my achievements.

[image]

Comment: I actually completed a few quests multiple times for other achievements. Besides, I am playing the game on hard difficulty without playing on normal, and complete some missions on brutal. Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: @Volkan İlbeyli There you have. It stacks up through the missions you play. Thats the reason you got those level achivements while not being that exact level in the game.